# Why HTML tags are not rendered properly in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, html, symfony1, escaping

I've got in this model the following method which reads a file and returns its content

```
public function getTest() {
  return file_get_contents($filePath);
}
```

And in the template I just output the result like this (I don't perform anything else on the $obj instance before this call)

```
<?php echo $obj->getTest() ?>
```

But the content doesn't render as a propel HTML. It display the BR tag instead of creating an empty line.

Here are the settings.yml regarding escaping:

```
all:
  .settings:
    escaping_strategy: false           
    escaping_method:   ESC_SPECIALCHARS
```

Answer (score 1):

I have few question:

- Did you clean your cache after changing settings.yml?
- Is there only one definition for `escaping_strategy` in your settings.yml? No specification for other environment (like dev:, prod:) ? (show us your full settings.yml)

On an other hand, it's not recommended to disabled escaping at all. What I usually did, is to enable it but for some point, when I'm sure at 100% that the content comme from a secure place  (file or db content that can't be altered by user), I display it by disable the escape strategy locally:

```
<?php echo sfOutputEscaper::unescape($obj->getTest()) ?>
```